# Admob issue with Package name

Tags: admob

I have one project which is already live on play Store. When I implement ads mob in that then ads was not showing by App and I got error code 0.

But when I change my package name then same project is working fine and ads shows within application.

Anybody knows Whats going on ? 
Because I want to implement ads in live application